# AngularJS: How to bind a scope variable in a view to an input element in parent template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have main template with a search box in the navigation bar.

I want to bind the search box to a variable in the view's scope.

How do I do that?

Comment: Can you explain it in more details?

Comment: I have a search box in the navigation bar at the top - just like this stackoverflow page. Imagine that the part below the black navigation bar is the view. The view has its own scope. I wan't to bind the search box to a variable in the view's scope. Since search box is in the parent template, the usual method of binding only binds to variables in the same scope as the html element.

Comment: use $parent.viewname..

Comment: i mean inside ng-model, use '$parent.' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your child scope inherits from parent it will have access to parent's variables. Have a look at the working example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codeepic/rjndsfdL/2/) where updating parent's `ng-model='user.name'` is visible in child scope.

Comment: I am using views. But it works with views too. Thanks for the JSFiddle.